# Prove Cantor's Theorem

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I have read proofs of the theorem using 'Diagonalization' method or the proof by 'contradiction'. I have shared my approach of the proof. I want to know whether the proof is correct or not. 
**Approach :**
We can define an injection between the elements of a set $A$ to its power set $2^A$, such that $f$ maps elements from $A$ to corresponding singleton sets in $2^A$. Since we have an extra element $\phi$ in $2^A$ which cannot be lifted back to $A$, hence we can state that $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only proves that the function that you defined from $A$ into $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is not surjective. It doesn't prove that there is no surjective function from $A$ onto $\mathcal{P}(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

@JoséCarlosSantos has already explained why your proof doesn't work, so let's see one that does. Given $f:\,A\mapsto\mathcal{P}(A)$, define $B:=\{x\in A|x\notin f(x)\}$, so $\forall x\in A(x\in B\iff x\notin f(x))$. Hence $\forall x\in A(f(x)\ne B)$. But $B\in\mathcal{P}(A)$, so $f$ isn't surjective.